# python: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to write a python code on python 3.10 with selenium to automize the loging in my gmail account. There is something false with Xpath.

The Error that I am getting is **selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator**

Below is my code

````
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:/Users/user/Desktop/chromedriver.exe"))
browser.get("https://www.google.de/")

browser.fullscreen_window()
time.sleep(1)
login = browser.find_element("By.XPATH", "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
login.click()
time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()```

I tried to change the Xpath but it didn't work. I thought that is something false with selenium code then I uninstalled the selenium and installed it again but it didn't work.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newcomer...

Google first. Selenium has been industry standard since I remember, this has been posted in THOUSAND sites.

In short, `"By.XPATH"` is pretty wrong. You pass a string there, you has to pass the function.

So, go back to google (or even here- search ...), and find how to import By function in selenium (like you did with selenium) then pass the method like `login = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")` and you'll fine.

Remember this after ask very common questions like this, you have THOUSAND of lines examples of everything in google. Spend your time reading.

Comment: Thanks for your information it worked i will pay attention to read the articles

Comment: Rigth now, the method By is the official one, the older way are deprecated (ie: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector -> By.CSS_SELECTOR). In case of my latest versions is removed so I had to modify most of the code. You can check current driver object functions by `print(dir(driver))`..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes in By.XPATH -

```
browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='gb']/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a")
```

and import By:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```